# component testing using camel framework with multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel

I am testing a component using camel test kit.

I send the data to the endpoint using

```
template.sendBodyAndHeaders(theEndpoint, data, headers);
```

and after this statement I assert the mocked endpoints using

```
assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
```

But the problem is the endpoint takes some times(based on the input) for processing, thus my assert condition fail because the mocked queue haven't received data yet.

In order to solve the problem, I tried using

```
1. Thread.sleep(1000L);
```

But as I said that processing time changes with the input, it fails at times. I cannot increase time since it may be performance issue when testing with smaller input. Also tried,

```
2. synchronized (this) {
        this.wait();
        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    }
    synchronized (this) {
        template.sendBodyAndHeaders(theEndpoint, data, headers);
        template.notify();
    }
```

But this is a deadlock. I know the code is wrong and wont ever work. But multithreading is new to me, I have read about wait/notify still not able to come up with right solution.

Any idea how we can make this wait/notify work or any other solution to this problem which actually asserts only after the processing completes not not based on hardcorded timeout value?

Comment: Could you post the route you are testing as well? sendBodyAndHeaders() is a blocking call. So normally the call should not return before your route has processed the body.

Comment: True but the route may do other things like wiretap which are async. Perhaps the variants of `assertIsSatisfied` with timeout argument could help=

Comment: @Ralf that route calls a bean which in turn calls the process method of processor class which does complete processing of the component, calling many different methods all over the component... Hope am clear!!!

Comment: @vikingsteve timeout argument would do the same which Thread.sleep() does, I need some way where I don't have to hard-code timeout value...

Comment: I was thinking if it always takes less than 10 seconds then you could try a timeout value of `10000`. But, ok, I'm out of ideas, lets see if someone more knowledgeable can solve this... ;)

Comment: If your route contains asynchronous elements, then you need some sort of callback to tell you when that task has finished. What you might be able to do in your unit test is to mock whatever receives the final result of the async process and then call you back from that mock to tell the test code that the process has finished.

Comment: I can't change the developed code. However, what I have in place is: Once the processing completes, it sends notification to a topic. Can we do something like when that topic gets the exchange, testing code gets the notification for the same?

Answer (score 0):

How about using [NotifyBuilder](http://camel.apache.org/notifybuilder.html), you can let the builder time out to be 5 seconds and your test don't have to wait for 5 seconds.

Comment: I found it a good solution, but this doesn't seems to work. Below is my code.

`NotifyBuilder notify = new NotifyBuilder(context).whenDone(1).wereSentTo("activemq:topic:topicName").create();`
`template.sendBodyAndHeaders(theEndpoint, data, headers);`

`boolean match = notify.matches(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

`if(match) assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();`
but match is always false.

Comment: Please make sure the camel context holds the route which sends the message to "activemq:topic:topicName", if you don't want to setup the activemq broker in your unit test, you can just replace the "activemq:xxx" to "direct:xxx".

Comment: Camel context doesn't hold that route. I cannot modify original camel context. I tried to include a new camel-context tag in the text.xml, but then it doesn't start any route. (since now there are two camel-context)

Comment: test.xml* i meant. Let me know if its not clear, i will add my camel-contexts for reference. Thanx.

Comment: You need use the original camel context to setup the NotifyBuilder.

Comment: I cannot use original camel context. Because of reasons I mentioned. Any other solution?